# JSF webpage template design

Tags: jsf, jdeveloper, oracle-adf

how can i design an jsf webpage template using adf so that I can type any text in any part (center) part of the derived page from that template page.

There will be an template page created in jsf using adf. Another jsf page is to be created based on that template and i can able to type any text on the center part of the webpage.

Comment: Depends on the view technology you're using. Is it JSP or Facelets?

Comment: its fecet of JSF that i am using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you create a jsf template and add a facet in the center using some type of "placeholder" layout manager.
When you create a new jsf page based on the template the facet will be in the center and you can drag other components to it.

Comment: np - let me know if you need any more help: joe.greenwald@oracle.com - Consider using the PanelStrectchLayout for the template - the center of the layout can hold your main content and stretches its children to fit.

Comment: Hi 
i am using ADF technology ....
I have an command link in which I have added and show popup behavior with a dialog to display a popup… if I add an action listener in  that command link that action listener never gets called ….
As I need that action listener to get the value of an attribute which is added in that command link.

How can I perform action listener and show popup behavior together or one by one when the command link is clicked?
Please help!!

Comment: try setting the link's PartialSubmit property to TRUE - this causes the link to immediately do a FORM post back, _without_ a page refresh. YOu can also try the immediate property as well, but PartialSubmit should do it for you